# VSCode extension development unable to use provideInlineCompletionItems

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've tried so many variations of this from code I found on github using the provideInlineCompletionItems function but cannot seem to get it to work. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
const vscode = require('vscode');

function activate(context) {
    const provider = {
        provideInlineCompletionItems: async (document, position, context, token) => {
            const txt = 'hi'
            return [
                {
                    text: txt,
                    insertText: txt,
                    range:new vscode.Range(position.translate(0, txt.length), position)
                }
            ]
        },
    };
    vscode.languages.registerInlineCompletionItemProvider({pattern: "**"}, provider);
}
exports.activate = activate;

function deactivate() {}

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
};
```

Even with https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125663 and "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true, set to true it doesn't work. I know inline suggestions works since I have github copilot, I just can't seem to get it to work. Copilot is also disabled so they don't interfere

Comment: first get the completion example working

Comment: @rioV8 yeah I tried, it doesn't work. this is not much more I can think of to do, it should be a simple process

Answer (score 1):

I rollbacked a version of VSCode and it works now. this is the debug code I used.

```
// The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
const vscode = require('vscode');

// This method is called when your extension is activated
// Your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed

/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
function activate(context) {

    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "seven" is now active!');

    // The command has been defined in the package.json file
    // Now provide the implementation of the command with  registerCommand
    // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('seven.helloWorld', function () {
        // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed

        // Display a message box to the user
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from seven!');
    });

    const provider = {
        provideInlineCompletionItems: async (document, position, context, token) => {
            const line = document.lineAt(position.line);
            console.log("420")
            if (line.text.startsWith('if')) {
                console.log("421")
                let range = line.range;
                if (line.text.indexOf(";") !== -1) {
                    console.log("423")
                    range = new vscode.Range(range.start, range.end.with(undefined, line.text.indexOf(";") + 1));
                }
                console.log("424")

                return [{ text: 'if (hello) {\n};', insertText: "if (hello)", range }];
            }
        }
    };

    vscode.languages.registerInlineCompletionItemProvider({ pattern: '**' }, provider);

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);

    
}

// This method is called when your extension is deactivated
function deactivate() {}

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
}
```